# C# Unity 3D add point every full rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, angle

So i have been looking for about an hour for a solution to my problem and i haven't yet found on so i am on here. 
My problem is that i want to count how many full rotations i do, i have a spinning object, and every full rotation i want to keep a score, i cant calculate the time it takes and then add points on like that, because the speed of the spinning object will be constantly changing, so that wont work. I would ideally also be able change the angle at which you gain a point. Or if say every 1 degrees i rotate, it would add a point on like that, anything i would just like to calculate how many times i have rotated. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current x y or z rotation from your gameobject and then in update you can look if it rotated.
Example for 10 unit for one point:

1. Your gameobject has rotation equals 20 - save that value in a variable called rot outside the update method.
2. Update is called. Your game objects rotation is now 25 - in update you look if the 10 is fitting in 25 - rot. 25 - rot is 5 - so doesn t fit.
3. Update is called. Your gameobject rotation is now 42 - calculate: 42 - rot is equals 22. You see it fits. Now calculate how many times 10 fits into 22. It fits 2 times. So add 2 points to the score. Now set rot equals old rot value plus 2 times 10.

Comment: this doesn't work for what i am doing as it is going to be spinning extremely fast, like 50 full rotations per second, but thanks though

Comment: i am completely confused by what you mean with this

Comment: Wait a moment i will try to explain it again

Comment: I do not understand how rotating from 20 degrees to 42 degrees works out to 2 full rotations.

Comment: Not to 2 full rotations. I mean 2 rotations that are giving points. So 20 units.

Comment: Can you post your solution so other people can see how it works?